# How to get past comments of a user? Column not found error

Tags: laravel

I have a UserController that has the index() method that should get all the past comments in posts by a user and for each comment get the post details (title and date). So I have the code below to get the past comments of a user:

```
$pastComments = $user->comments()->with('post')->where('create_date', '<', now())->get();
```

The create_date is a field of the posts table, not comments table.

But it appears an error:

```
"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'create_date' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `comments` where `comments`.`user_id` = 1 and `comments`.`user_id` is not null and `create_date` < 2018-05-08 15:04:47)".
```

Do you know why?

Models:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function posts(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post', 'user_id');
    }
    public function comments(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment','user_id');
    }
}

class Comment extends Model
{
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
    public function post(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
    }

}


class Post extends Model
{
    public function admin(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
    }
    public function comments(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment', 'post_id');
    }
}
```

Tables structure:

```
Users table: id, name, ...
Comments table: id, post_id, user_id, ...
Posts table: id, name, user_id, ...
```

With:

```
$comments = $user->comments()->with('post')->whereHas(['post' => function ($query) {$query->where('create_date', '<', now()); }])->get();
```

It appears:

```
  strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

Comment: post your migration too

Comment: I think you must set table name where isset column create_date for example table.create_date

Comment: `WhereHas` doesn't accept and array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to scope a query by its relationship you'll need to use `whereHas` e.g.

```
$pastComments = $user->comments()->with('post')
        ->whereHas('posts', function ($query) {
            $query->where('create_date', '<', now());
        })
        ->get();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

Comment: Thanks, then to show the info of the post is not like this:  "@foreach($pastComments as $pastComment)
 <h1>{{$pastComment->post->name}}</h1>
  @enforeach"? Because its appearing "Trying to get property of non-object".

Comment: @johnW I did notice that you're arguments are the wrong way round in your `foreach` as it should be `$pastComment as $pastComments`, however, there could be something else going wrong there. I would make sure that it's definitely that piece of code and then use `dd()` to find out what is actually missing.

Answer (score 1):

[Constraining Eager Loads](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads)

```
$pastComments = $user->comments()->with(['post' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('create_date', '<', now());
}])->get();
```